# How to redirect top command after grep concurrently

Tags: bash, shell, concurrency, grep

I want to make script that will write top command result to a file concurrently (as a background process). For example:

`top -b -c | grep 'grep' > out.txt &`

But it outputting an empty string

Then I tried to use parenthesis
`(top -b -c | grep 'grep' > out.txt) &`

Still no luck. Is there something I've been missing?

p.s. `grep 'grep'` is just for example

Comment: You can try the `grep` option `--line-buffered` if your version handles it.

Comment: wow, it works @gniourf_gniourf thank you very much